# Handling tbody when adding rows to an empty table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an empty table in my code like so:

```
<table id='rostertable'></table>
```

When I add a `<tr>` using jQuery's `append` function, then according to my chrome inspector, my table looks like this:

```
<table id='rostertable'><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

It seems like the tbody got added by itself, and this causes problems later when I'm traversing the DOM.

For consistency's sake, I figured it would be better if I added the tbody myself and appended directly to it. Is this possible? I tried making my placeholder `<table id='rostertable'><tbody></tbody></table>` but the jQuery selector `$('#rostertable tbody')` returns null and my chrome inspector doesn't show the tbody tags either.

**Edit:** Never mind, it ended up being an unrelated bug in my javascript. At one point I was clearing out the contents of the table and running $("#rostertable").html(""), which of course deleted the tbody. I accepted the first valid answer to this question.

Comment: show us your jquery code

Comment: when you are appending the browser adds the tbody tags

Comment: You could use [$table.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) instead of `$table.html("")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `not` get `null`, if no element matches the selector still you will get `object` containing `zero` elements.

Your selector is returning tbody and you might be using some wrong method.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HUw5/1/)**

```
alert($('#rostertable tbody').html());​
```

Comment: It turned out to be an unrelated bug, but I accepted your answer since it seems like a valid answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To append to the `tbdoy` your code should work as long as you append valid html.

The below works ok:

```
$('#rostertable tbody').append('<tr><td>new row - cell 1</td><td>new row - cell 2</td></tr>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nTaDf/)

You need to make sure you append a `<td>` as well as the `<tr>`. For example in Chrome, the following will simple add an empty `<tr>`

```
$('#rostertable tbody').append('<tr>no cells added, just row</tr>');​
```